# Adding unallocated partition to Ubuntu in VMware

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, gparted

I've installed Ubuntu 9.10 on a Windows XP using vmware.  As most do, I initially setup the size of the virtual drive to 8GB and soon realized I need more.  I used the VMware utility to expand the virtual drive and added another 4GB, which I can see using GParted.  Now my dilemma is how can I "merge" the newly created space to my original?

[image: this screenshot]

I need to add the unallocated space.  I tried before and after formatting the new space but still whenever I try to resize/move `/dev/sda1` it looks like it is using its maximum capacity.  Also, GParted is being used from the GParted live CD not from the Linux live CD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use gparted to delete your Linux Swap, expand your /dev/sda1 to most of the available space, and then create a new Swap at the end.

Answer (score 1):

1. Resize `/dev/sda2` to the maximum allowed value. Apply.
2. Move `/dev/sda5` (swap), that's inside of /dev/sda2, to the end. Apply.
3. Resize `/dev/sda2` again, but now to the minimum allowed value. Apply.

   Now you will see the "unallocated space" has moved to the center,
   between `/dev/sda1` & `/dev/sda2`.
4. You can now resize `/dev/sda1` to a maximum allowed value which includes the unallocated space. Yay! Apply.

Answer (score 0):

You should use gparted live latest version stable (google it and download). Boot with gparted live cd after burn iso.
Do what you read at first answer but with this gparted live, aply, exit gparted , boot normally from disk. You should see your space.